# JVM and Java Linux process

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, jvm

This question may be very basic about Java JVM.  If I've a Java standalone program and if, for example, 5 processes of this program are running at a particular time in the server, can we say that these 5 java processes are running in 5 JVMs?

By process, I mean the Linux process here.  If I execute `ps -ef |grep java`, I'll see 5 java processes showing up.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jvmtop/ displays all jvms

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.  There is one JVM per `java` process.

Comment: Can we say # of java processes equals # of JVMs running at all cases?

Comment: In a normal Linux setup, as described in your question.  There are possible solutions for attempting more than one JVM per process.  See [this (old) article](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/09/25/optimization.html), for instance.

Answer (score 5):

You can run the `jps` command (from the bin folder of JDK if it is not in your path) to find out what java processes (JVMs) are running on your machine.

Comment: @Gnanam : You will find the `jps` command useful in another situation. It is normally used to find out the process id of your java process, which can be passed to an application like a profiler like VisualVM (invoked with `jvisualvm` comamnd) or the `jhat` utility to take heap dumps.

Comment: Thanks once again for letting me know the existence of another Heap Analysis tool [`jhat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the JVM and native libs.  You may see JVM threads show up with distinct PIDs in `ps`.  Generally speaking the child PIDs will have parent PIDs with java processes as those that are threads.

You cannot say for sure that the # of Linux java processes == # of instantiated JVMs.

Comment: On Linux, the JVM uses true native threads, which are *similar* to processes.  However, they are not the same thing, as only a process has its own address space.

Comment: I'm addressing your last paragraph.  I think you can say that (process count *does* equal JVM count) for sure, regardless of `ps` output.